# SQLAlchemy: column_property jsonb operation

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, jsonb

My `Test` table has a JSONB column `data`:

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    data = Column(JSONB)
```

A typical document has two lists:

```
{'percentage': [10, 20, 50, 80, 90],
'age': [1.21, 2.65, 5.23, 8.65, 11.78]
}
```

With a [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) I would like to tailor this two lists so it is available as a dictionary. In "open field" Python this is straightforward:

```
dict(zip(Test.data['percentage'], Test.data['age']))
```

But with a column_property:

```
Test.data_dict = column_property(
    dict(zip(Test.data['percentage'], Test.data['age']))
)
```

this gives:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'label'

Is this actually possible and how should this been done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it solves your problem?

```
@property
def data_dict(self):
    return dict(zip(Test.data['percentage'], Test.data['age']))
```

Comment: `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`

Comment: Excuse me, replace `Test.data` with `self.data`

Comment: thanks, this works; however it is a temporary fix for me since I want to use `column_property`'s options like `deferred` and `info`

Comment: `class Test:... data_dict = column_property(dict(zip(self.data['percentage'], self.data['age')))`. Could you try it?

Comment: `self` is unknown outside the `@property`

Comment: Excuse me again:) there is no `self`inside class definition. Use just `data['percentage']` and `data['age'] `

Comment: the initial `NotImplementedError` again

Comment: If you want to perform data_dict as SQL query, you should use [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#mapper-sql-expressions) - `hybrid_property` with specified `property.expression`. Or you can do it using python, by `property` decorator, as I wrote before

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL it would something like this (for PostgreSQL >= 9.4)

```
SELECT json_object(array_agg(ARRAY[p,a]))
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'percentage'))) p,
           unnest(ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'age'))) a
    FROM test
) x;
```

In SQLAlchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
from sqlalchemy import select, alias, text
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    data = db.Column(JSONB)
    data_dict = column_property(
        select([text('json_object(array_agg(ARRAY[p,a]))')]).select_from(
            alias(select([
                text("unnest(ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'percentage'))) p, \
                      unnest(ARRAY(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'age'))) a")
            ]).select_from(text('test')))
        )
    )
```